# What causes the residual magnetic flux when the current is zero in an inductor hysteresis curve?

Tags: current, electromagnetism, inductance, magnetic-flux

An inductor with hysteresis has the following current versus flux curve:

[image]

I marked the point in red where the current is reduced to zero but there is still flux on the above curve.

What really causes this permanent magnet like magnetic flux in the absence of any current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is that it's the residual magnetism in the core (that graph refers to an inductor with a magnetic core).

It's the level of this residual that makes the difference between magnetically 'soft' materials that are used for inductor cores, where this residual should be as small as possible, ideally zero, and 'magnets', magnetically hard materials that retain a large field in the absence of external field. There's a lot of materials engineering goes making the former softer and the latter harder, annealing, alloying, heat treatment etc etc.

The [Ferromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism) article in Wikipedia gives a thorough if somewhat dry overview of what's going on.

The problem with your question is the word 'really'. There are several explanations at different levels for what causes magnetic materials to exhibit magnetism in the first place, and residual magnetism as per your question. You might talk about domains, or polarisation, or go all the way down to quantum mechanics, and if we knew what was below that (if anything), then we could go there as well. If you're happy with a reality based on one of those, then that should suffice. However some people want a more philosophical answer, and physics doesn't do that.

Comment: I meant I can relate the flux or H field to the current flowing. But what phenomena causes this flux if not such current? Is that polarization of what?

Comment: I've linked a wikipedia artcile

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into deep physics or math, consider that the molecules of an iron rod have magnetic moments (are magnetic domains) that are magnetically at random orientations. Initially, you would not measure an external magnetic field. However, when an electrified coil surrounds the rod the small magnetic field of the coil "induces" the magnetic domains to align in a common alignment thus greatly increasing the magnetic field around the rod. The domains themselves are the source of the strong magnetism; not the coil itself. Now, when the coil or its current is removed, the domains largely return to a random orientation but not all of them (depending upon the hardness of the iron). Therefore, there remains the residual magnetism.